# Why do I have to include an index?

Tags: smallbasic

So I found this code online (usually I do C# however I'm trying to teach smallbasic to a friend of mine) that basically reads a file:

```
TextWindow.Write("Enter the name of the new directory: ")
DirectoryName = TextWindow.Read()
files = File.GetFiles(DirectoryName)        
TextWindow.WriteLine("This is the content in the file: ")   
TextWindow.WriteLine(File.ReadContents(files[1]))
```

I understand what that all does, but why does it need to be `files[1]` instead of just `files`?

Removing the index `[1]` just makes the line not work, the program still compiles and whatnot.

SB doesn't have a debugger and the resources online aren't very good.

Comment: When the line doesn't work, is there a specific error message?  I imagine it needs the indexer because `files` is a collection of some type and `File.ReadContents()` expects a single instance of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API documents, `File.GetFiles` returns an array:

> If the operation was successful, this will **return the files as an array**. Otherwise, it will return "FAILED".

You specify an index because it returns an array and `File.ReadContents` expects a single instance.

View the API here: http://smallbasic.com/doc/?id=6